# what is ISCP in Telecom

Tags: telecommunication

Anybody let me know:

- 1. what is ISCP, is it a hardware device / software in telecom ?
- 2. How is it related to IBM, does it supports ISCP software ?
     Could be helpful if any link provided as well

Answer (score 1):

The Integrated Service Control Point (ISCP) was developed in the late 80s by two brilliant engineers, John O'Brien and Dave Babson, at Bellcore in NJ.  Initial development was funded by Bell Atlantic.  It was revolutionary in its use of "microcomputers" to implement flexible services using the SS7 network that sits aside of the regular Telco networks.  Aside from the services, the infrastructure of the ISCP was designed for very high performance and reliability.  The maximum downtime allowed under any circumstance was 1 minute/year.  The ISCP provides services as software programs rather than hardcoded switches.  IBM was chosen as the vendor to provide the hardware (RS6000s and AIX) to implement the network interfaces and signalling services.  The ISCP was meant to replace the SCPs that weren't as flexible and based on VAX/VMS.

Answer (score 0):

ISCP(Integrated Services Control Point) means

> A software system that integrates service control point (SCP) features
>   that allow for the efficient deployment of customized intelligent
>   network services.
>   It is a system software in telecom.

*IBM SmartCloud Orchestrator 2.2.0 supports installing the ISCP.cfg file and installing the first box.For Better understanding,please see the links provided.*

You can see the following links:
http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/rep_ca/8/897/ENUS100-288/ENUS100-288.PDF

http://www.prnewswire.co.uk/news-releases/iscp-software-takes-on-new-look-for-intelligent-networks-156550635.html

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4KMC_2.2.0/com.ibm.sco.doc_2.2/t_install_modify.html